# Как реализовать выборку категории при которой показывается нужные элементы? WPF+MVVM+MSSQL

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, mvvm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В базе SQL server есть таблицы categories и products, также есть внешний ключ в products от categories.

В MainWindow.xaml есть два Listbox

Этот для категорий

```
 <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="0">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="40,0"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,20">
                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Foreground="#fff" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                              <Button Margin="5" DataContext="{Binding ID_Category}" Click="select_category" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                     </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

А этот для продуктов

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="0,50">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Width="250" Height="370" Margin="40,0,0,0" Background="#121212">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="250" Height="200" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="#fff" Margin="15,15,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=ShortText}" Foreground="#9C9999" Margin="15,8,15,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="40"/>
                            <Grid Margin="15,8,15,0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Foreground="#fff" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Price}" Foreground="#fff" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Button DataContext="{Binding ID}" Content="To basket" FontSize="16" Background="#046902" Width="100" Height="30" Foreground="#fff" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="ToBasket"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

А в ViewModel я прописал так

```
public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        string sqlConnection = @"server=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DataBase=nanoEnergy;";
        string sqlCategory = "SELECT id_category,name FROM categories";
        string sqlItems = "SELECT img,name,discription,quantity,price,creator,year_of_issue,materials,id_product, id_category FROM products";
        string sqlPriceList = "SELECT * FROM price_list_view";

        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCategory, Connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  
                    Categories.Add(new Category
                    {
                        Title = reader.GetString(1),
                        ID_Category = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    });
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        };
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlItems, Connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    byte[] image = (byte[])(reader.GetValue(0));
                    object price = reader.GetValue(4);
                    string price_item = Convert.ToString(price); 
                    object year = reader.GetValue(6);
                    string year_item = Convert.ToString(year);

                    Items.Add(new Item
                    {
                        Image = image,
                        Name = reader.GetString(1),
                        ShortText = reader.GetString(2),
                        Quantity = reader.GetInt32(3),
                        Price = price_item,
                        Creator = reader.GetString(5),
                        Year = year_item,
                        Materials = reader.GetString(7),
                        ID = reader.GetInt32(8)
                    });
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        };

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Здесь Item:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private byte[] image;
        private string name;
        private int quantity;
        private string price;
        private string shorttext;
        private string creator;
        private string year;
        private string materials;
        private int i_id;
    
        public int ID
        {
            get { return i_id; }
            set
            {
                i_id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
        public string Creator
        {
            get { return creator; }
            set
            {
                creator = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Creator");
            }
        }
        public string Year
        {
            get { return year; }
            set
            {
                year = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Year");
            }
        }
        public string Materials
        {
            get { return materials; }
            set
            {
                materials = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Materials");
            }
        }

        public byte[] Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set
            {
                image = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set
            {
                quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }

        public string Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }
        public string ShortText
        {
            get { return shorttext; }
            set
            {
                shorttext = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShortText");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Так вот, не доходит до ума чтобы передать id таблицы categories в таблицу products, видимо чего-то очень важного не понимаю, чтобы сделать это.

Подскажите, что нужно лучше сделать, чтобы достичь выборки категории?

Comment: кажется, вы совсем не в ту степь забрели, какую задачу вы решаете? сейчас ответ звучит так: что бы вы не написали в этих скобках, работать не будет. Начните с того, что надо понять, что именно делает `new MainWindow()`, как оно работает. Если вы думаете, что дает вам доступ к основному окну, то это не так. Оно создает второе основное окно, и если вы вызовете `mainWindow.Show()`, то своими глазами в этом убедитесь.

Comment: @aepot Решаю задачу по сути с коллекциями, у меня есть в базе sql servel таблица category, а также есть таблица products в которой есть id соответственно, мне нужно при выборе category показывать по ней продукцию. Сейчас я изменю свою вопрос и код внутри. Предупреждаю, код у меня ужасен:)

Comment: XAML разметку не забудьте показать.

Comment: @aepot Да, mainWindow.Show(); будет вызывать новое окно, именно его в своей недопрограмме использую его частенько.

Comment: `Click="ToBasket"` - использование обработчиков событий в данном ключе - это не MVVM, в MVVM с контролами не работают в C# (почти никогда), а работают с данными. Что вы хотите добиться то? Что должен делать метод `select_category`, и зачем вы ему добавили аргумкенты как обработчику события, если он не обработчик события? Откуда он будет вызван с этими аргументами? Нужно больше кода или рассказ поподробнее. В курсе ли вы что вместо обработчиков `Click` можно использовать команды `ICommand`?

Comment: Еще вместо `Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(N))` можно использовать `reader.GetString(N)`, и там много еще разных методов для разных типов данных, напишите `reader.` и вам вывалится целый список, в котором много всего интересного.

Comment: Используете ли вы MVVM фреймворк? Покажите модель данных `Item`. Реализует ли модель данных `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Если да, то как именно?

Comment: @aepot 1) Насчёт события Click стало ясно, что это не MVVM. 2) Хочу добиться чтобы при выборе категории, показывались элементы(Products), которые находятся именно в этой категории. 3) select_category, Вообще я думал при событии он обработает, но видимо что нет. 4) Как раз откуда бы был вызван, так и не дошло:(. 5) Насчёт ICommand только сегодня узнал о нём. Если больше объяснений, то загружу фото программы, там будет нужно. Насчёт больше кода, тоже загружу, но не особо уверен, что он весь будет нужен

Comment: @aepot Сейчас поправлю у себя на reader.GetString(N).

Comment: @aepot Нет, я не использую фраймворки. Код Item тоже сейчас загружу:)

Comment: Сразу обновите тогда код в вопросе, он станет заметно короче. Вы можете прямо внтури `Items.Add(new Item {...})` вызывать `reader.Get...(..)`.

Comment: @aepot изменил reader, но не везде, так как дата и цену не знаю как лучше записать, попробовал но пока не вышло, потихоньку буду разбираться. За сокращение спасибо:)

Comment: С ценой все просто, она у вас в базе как число? Вот и храните как число, а если хотите баксы пририсовать, сделайте это например в интерфейсе. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={0}$}" ...` - [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.3.php), или в свойстве внутри `Item` - `public string PriceText => Price + " $";` + `Text="{Binding PriceText}`. Как вам удобнее, а модель данных в приложении должна быть в совместимых с базой форматах.

Comment: @aepot В базе цена float, поначалу ставил money, но вот только 4 нуля после запятой покою не давали, поэтому и поменял его, но да:), мне нужны баксы

Comment: `public string PriceText => Price.ToString("F2") + " $";`, где `public float Price` или `double`, не важно. [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) или соовтетвтенно `StringFormat={0:F2} $` - два нуля после запятой. P.S. значок бакса ставится перед числом по стандарту :) `$1,000`

Comment: @aepot посмеялся с себя, когда прочитал P.S. Ну а так, "F2" для чего?

Comment: F2 - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте команду

#### RelayCommand

Добавьте вот такой класс себе в проект

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

#### UI

Тогда кнопки должны у вас такие

```xml
<Button Margin="5"
        Background="Transparent"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

```xml
<Button Content="To basket"
        FontSize="16"
        Background="#046902"
        Width="100" Height="30"
        Foreground="#fff"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ToBasketCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

#### Команды

При таких привязках команды должны быть расположены во вьюмодели окна и выглядеть так

```cs
private ICommand _selectCategoryCommand;

public ICommand SelectCategoryCommand => _selectCategoryCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is Category category)
    {
        // здесь выполняйте код, category - это объект категории, в который юзер ткнул
    }
});

private ICommand _toBasketCommand;

public ICommand ToBasketCommand => _toBasketCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is Item item)
    {
        // здесь выполняйте код, item - это объект Item, в который юзер ткнул
    }
});
```

#### CanExecute

Есть еще одна фича, `CanExecute` называется, вы можете добавить условие, которое будет делать элемент интефейса неактивным, прямо в команду, и если оно вернет `false`:

1. команда не будет выполнена
2. `IsEnabled` элемента станет `false` автоматически

пользоваться так:

```cs
public ICommand ToBasketCommand=> _toBasketCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    Item item = (Item)parameter; // так как проверка на is Item уже выполнена в CanExecute, 
    // можно выполнять сразу каст, потому что CanExecute дает гарантию,
    // что команда не будет выполнена, если CanExecute == false

    // здесь выполняйте код, item - это объект Item, в который юзер ткнул
}, parameter => parameter is Item item && item.Quantity > 0);
```

Все кнопки у элементов с `Quantity == 0` будут вырублены и кнопка `To Basket` не будет работать. Сами придумайте, как это можно использовать. Условие перепроверяется автоматически каждый раз, когда юзер ткнул в интерфейс или нажал на клавиатуру, то есть когда произошло событие любого ввода.

Вызвать перепроверку всех `CanExecute` вручную можно вот так:

```cs
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

Только если вы будете использовать многопоточность, этот метод можно вызывать только из UI потока, в противном случае он просто не сработает.

Comment: Ого, теперь думаю что когда стану хорошо понимать программирование, буду также помогать как и вы. Хороший пример. Ещё раз большое спасибо:)

Comment: @AstronautPavel работает? отлично! вслепую на коленке писал. :)

Comment: Ахахах:), Да, только ещё ищу про команды ICommand, так как ещё слабовато разбираюсь:)

Comment: @AstronautPavel важно `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}` - это перенаправление привязки в окно, если это убрать и написать просто `Command="{Binding SelectCategoryCommand}"`, то команда будет искаться в текущем `DataContext`, то есть внутри класса `Item` или `Category` соответственно, а не во вьюмодели окна. Соответственно, если вы делаете команды для кнопок за пределами коллекции, а просто в интерфейсе, то вам не нужен `RelativeSource`, потому что `DataContext` этих кнопок будет и так указывать на нужную вьюмодель.

Comment: @AstronautPavel в смысле работает? о_О не должно, сейчас баг исправлю. Исправил. `Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCategoryCommand,...` Если у вас команды в классе Window - унесите их в вьюмодель окна `ApplicationViewModel`, они там должны быть. В идеале, при правильном MVVM в классе `Window` ничего не должно быть, вообще пусто, только одинокий `InitializeComponent(); DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();` в конструкторе.

Comment: Ах да, не написал, да DataContext не хватало, он у меня ругался, но я его добавил. Просто наугад написал, даже не знал и вот, больше не ругался на него:)

Comment: Вот то что важно в копилочку знаний!!!

Comment: @AstronautPavel ну теперь у вас код должен собраться в одну кучу, а то события в одном классе, свойства в другом, куча перекрестных ссылок. Чем меньше класс связан с внешним миром, тем легче его допиливать/перепиливать. Суть MVVM в максимально возможном ослаблении связей между компонентами приложения.

Comment: суть как я понимаю, точнее аналогия меньше материального недосчастья, больше свободы внутри себя. Ну это так, лирика. А вообще мне интересно, вот думал на web перейти, так вот можно ли в WPF использовать как web, то есть исполнитель визуалки за место браузерв?

Comment: @AstronautPavel не понял вопроса, поэтому ответ "нет". Есть специальный `ASP.NET Core` для веба.

Comment: А что насчет десктопных приложений, например социальные сети какие-нибудь ну или просто проги, которые с API связываются и используют только его.

Comment: @AstronautPavel десктопные приложения не так популярны, если это только что-то реально крупное или игра. Вся мелочь уехала в мобильный рынок, там вас встретит Xamarin.Forms, и там кстати XAML как в WPF.

Comment: о да, Xamarin.Forms ноут туго тянет, а вот в коллеже того года сделал на нём откровенное д****, но оно было лучшим. API у nasa спёр. Ох, хорошо с вами знания получать, но нужно дальше пилить прогу, а то курсач по времени к концу подходит. Все мои одногруппники  через datagrid, а я без него:)  При многом благодарен^-^